Why does this official Arduino book recommend to use an LED with no resistor?
I am reading this book, which is by the Arduino's inventor himself. I am amazed that in the first two examples he uses an LED without any resistor whatsoever to limit the current going through it.

Why could it be a good idea in some case, or couldn't it and the book is absurdly crazy in recommending that?

Instead of linking the book as a product, which shows nothing about the specific circuit, consider instead quoting or photographing the schematic and relevant text.

I'll try to come back later within answer BUT - this is an attempt at simplification for beginners but it is more than a bridge too far. If he must make the suggestion he needs to explain why it is a very bad thing to do and the potential consequences and why you would not usually do it. He fails very badly. || He says: ... Your Arduino board comes with an LED preinstalled. It’s marked “L”. You can also add your own LED—connect it as shown in Figure 4-2. If you intend to keep the LED lit for a long period of time, you should use a resistor as described on page 56."

I wouldn't recommend this. On a 3.3V supply, especially with a blue or white LED, it's probably okay, but the author shows a 5V Arduino Uno and does not remark on the LED colour. It's certainly not guaranteed to damage the LED or the MCU, but it's not guaranteed not to.

Isn't that exactly the spirit of Arduino? Over-simplificate everything ridiculously, to the point where the practices are easy to learn but technically incorrect. So we quickly learn how to not do things.

It does not "recommend" (it even mentions the recommended way). It does over simplify things, as Lundin mentioned. It is hard to judge the decision to present a technically wrong solution to kids, which certainly creates the incentives to keep learning.

@MeGrogu Considering this image directly from the book, it certainly appears to be  a recommended course of action.

@Lundin My favourite pet peeve in that category: analogWrite(), which does not, in fact, do anything analog. The number of beginners this confuses is astronomical. Dodgy practices from someone Arduino-affiliated do not amaze me.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany. I agree. I just considered that the clear warning in the page before the image you mention states that this is not the correct way. This warning mentions other circuit later in the book where there is a resistor and a breadboard. What I find interesting is that arduino has lots of these obviously wrong examples, also in software. It is just a matter of us looking at them and trying to avoid the "Aahhh, my eyes" feeling, when they serve another purpose, far away from engineering.

@MeGrogu No such warning appears in the 2008 edition. Nor does any warning appear in the 2009 edition. It does in the 2011 edition.

it depends on the led i think

@jyelton I certainly considered that but I didn't want to infringe any copyright.

A small excerpt of the book (with proper attribution) certainly would qualify as fair use.

@JYelton pic added. Not sure how to add attribution but I guess it's implicit, I state from the beginning what book is that from.


"If you intend to keep the LED lit for a long period of time, you should use a resistor as described on page 56"

Not that I agree with the extreme simplicity, but the author had his reasons (like, probably, showing a first example without even requiring a wire).
Later, the PWM example does recommend a 270 \$\Omega\$ resistor in series with the LED.
This is to be found in the microcontroller datasheet:

So it should be fine for a short test and a small LED.

When doing educational outreach to kids who have no circuits experience, it is MUCH better to just omit the resistor.  I've honestly never seen an LED die in this way, so the simplicity is definitely worth it.

@Demis I've seen dozens of LEDs die in this way, so I'm not sure what you've been doing different.

@Demis Whether the LED burns, or something else that is not supposed to happen, is up to the circuit. Sometimes it's the MCU that burns. Depending on the power supply used, turning on the LED can simply clamp the MCU supply voltage so low that it resets or fails to run the program correctly. Omitting a resistor even for educational purposes from actual circuit is the reason why people think they can be omitted. In block diagrams omitting it is fine, in actual circuits and schematics, never. Same goes for bypass caps.

@Demis It is understandable in this context, considering that the author, at this point in the book, doesn't even want to mention that something like a resistor even exists. The warning above appears just before the drawing showing how to connect the LED directly to the board. He does mention the right way of connecting the LED. I'm not judging the authors decision on taking the risk of burning an LED or the uC.

"So it should be fine for a short test and a small LED." It entirely depends on how much kaboom the voltage source is able to deliver. The average 9V battery or bench supply will deliver kaboom within less than one second. A coin cell battery with internal ESR, not quite as kaboom:ish.

"It entirely depends on how much kaboom the voltage source is able to deliver. The average 9V battery or bench supply will deliver kaboom within less than one second." Sure, @Lundin. But we are not talking about the voltage source. We are talking about the GPIO of a specific uC on a specific board, configured as output.

@devnull Yeah that is unlikely to damage the LED, it will just damage the microcontroller...

Thanks for the feedback. "that is unlikely to damage the LED, it will just damage the microcontroller". "It will" is definitely a stronger statement than "it should".

Actually I think I remember one or two LED's dying when connected directly to a battery - it has usually happened after ~20-30min or more of usage, so again achieved it's intended educational purpose and sort of a wont fix.  For a real circuit where longevity is required, the resistor is important.

@Demis, well, it did say "if you intend to keep the LED lit for a long period of time...". I suppose one might as well read that as "if you intend for the LED to stay lit for a long period of time..."

I admittedly missed that note, although I still find that to be pretty anal. What are a "long" and a "short" period of time? I really think that simplicity of teaching should not justify such a bad design, but at the very least they put a rough note about that.

It's because a resistor is a magic "black box" that people with no electrical background will not understand.  If you have to explain lifetime, resistance and current, you'll have lost most 8 years olds and their teachers (eg. their parents). Removing this one component dramatically increases engagement, but might, as you point out, cost you a $1.00 LED bulb that burned out. Considering the mind of an 8 year old with no prior knowledge, it makes perfect sense to me, as I used to make such educational activies, see here: http://ips.ece.ucsb.edu/education.html

The drawing adds more context. The author went to the trouble of adding a pullup resistor to the switch (on a breadboard, even!) To get there the reader would have to grasp not only the idea of a resistor, but also of breadboards generally, and how to connect it to power and GND. Would it have been that off-putting to do the same for the LED? I don't think so.

@hacktastical Indeed. In the second example a breadboard is used.

Also, I think in terms of being off-putting, frying the LED, let alone the ATmega, would be far more frustrating to a learner than mastering the idea of a dropping resistor.

As to ‘why’? Simplicity, maybe? You could ask them I suppose.
At any rate the author did a bad thing and should feel bad. Connecting an LED without a dropping resistor means that all the IR drop is being taken by the I/O pad FET driver. That's very unkind to both the LED and the ATmega.
The ATmega Datasheet lists Absolute Maximum Ratings for I/O pin DC current as 40mA; for all pins together no more than 200mA:

We can estimate the Rds(on) for the driver, here:

From this chart we find that when sourcing 20mA the pin drops to 4.37V or so. We can compute Rds(on) for the high-side FET as:

Rds(on): (5 - 4.37V) / 20mA = 31.5 ohms

Note that the Rds(on) resistance will be at most that figure, to guarantee worst-case V(oh) level. Typical Rds(on) will be lower, perhaps as low as 20-25 ohms.
We can then use this figure to estimate the LED and I/O pad current:

3V LED: (5 - 3V)/31.5 ohms = 63mA
1.8V LED: (5 - 1.8V)/31.5 ohms =  102mA

Again, the currents will probably be higher than this for a typical part.
Operating in this out-of-spec condition for any appreciable length of time will damage the LED, the ATmega, or both.
Stepping back a bit, lighting LEDs is one of those rites of passage for electronics newbies. To a learner, it's somewhat magical: making that mysterious, cool light glow that has an otherworldly quality compared to a light bulb.
Learning to do it correctly with current limiting is worth the time, even for an eight-year-old. The alternative - a fried LED, or worse, fried ATmega - would be far more frustrating to a learner than just being guided up-front to use a 220 ohm resistor.
To make the idea more tangible, a teachable demo would be to sacrifice an LED by connecting it directly to 5V and GND and watching it go "poof". Then do the same thing with another LED, but with the resistor: no "poof", only the magic glow. This is also an opportunity to teach about LED polarity: how to spot the anode / cathode and how to connect them up.

All diodes including LEDs have internal resistance. If you drop the voltage so that the the series R would be 10 ohms at 10 mA or 0.1V below the nominal voltage you won't likely get a runaway issue.  But if you try to do this at max current of say 30mA, you will run into the risk of thermal runaway.
All CMOS logic gates have an RdsOn = Vol/Io which can be used to limit current on 3.1 V LEDs from 3.3V logic without using a resistor.  Even white 5 mm LEDs have an Rs = 12-16 ohms above 2.85V typically to estimate Vf.
The trick is to plan to operate at less than full brightness and allow for tolerances.
e.g. if using an Arduino ATMega48A @ 5V , the nominal Rout=(Voh-Vo)/Io or =Vol/Io = 31 ohms @ 85'C and 27.5 ohms @ 25'C.  Using a 5mm white LED with the characteristics of V=2.85 + If*15 Ohms  we get a rapidly burnt-out LED;
\$ΔV/R = \dfrac{(5-2.85)V}{(31+15)Ω}= 54 ~ mA = I_F \$ which is excessive.
 source p537
Whereas at 3V the Atmega direct driving a 5mm white LED will be ;
\$I_F = \dfrac{(5-2.85) }{( 42.5+15 ) }= 37 ~mA\$
Although LED's have very tiny gold wire bonds and only rated for 30 mA, one could PWM this  to reduce average power.

"If you drop the voltage so that ..." - This example is on an Arduino Uno, which outputs 5V and cannog bbe configured to output less. The simple fact is, if you power a typical indicator LED (as depicted) from an Arduino Uno gpio without series resistor, you will violate the maximum current spec of both the MCU pin (40mA) and the LED (typically 20mA). Your answer doesn't really apply here.

I'm sorry, @marcelm. I was only defining the Vdd conditions where this method is valid. More importantly, I was showing how to estimate LED current rather than opining on an assumption for oversimplified engineering.
